# Distributed transactions across Spring web applications

Tags: database, spring, transactions, jta, distributed-transactions

Imagine a Java ecosystem where three separate Spring web application is running in separate JVMs and on separate machines (no application server involved, just simple servlet containers). Two of these applications are using their own database accessed using JPA. Now the third application (a coordinator) provides services to the outside world and some service function executes remote operations which requires participation from the other two apps in a transactional manner, which means that if one of the applications fails to do the data manipulation in the database, the other should be rolled back as well. The problem is: how can this be achieved using Spring?

Currently we are using REST to communicate between the applications. Clearly this cannot support transactions, even though [there are efforts to make this happen](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/pautasso/talks/2012/soa-cloud-rest-tcc/rest-tcc.html#/title).

I've found JTA which is capable of organizing global transactions. JTA involves creating XAResource instances which are participating in the globally managed transactions. If i understood correctly, these XAResource instance can reside on separate JVMs. Initialization, commit and rollback of resources happens via JMS communication which means it requires a message broker to transfer messages between participants. There are various JTA implementation exists, I've found Atomikos which seems to be the most used.

Now the thing i don't see is how this all comes up if i have a Spring application on each application side. I've not found any example projects yet which is doing JTA over a network. Also i don't undertstand what are XAResources representing. If i use JPA, and say i have a Account object in an application which stores a user's balance, and i have to decrease the balance from the coordinator, should i create an XAResource implementation which allows decreasing the balance? Or XAResource is implemented by a lower level thing like the JDBC driver or Spring Data JPA? In the latter case how can i provide high level CRUD operations for the transaction coordinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAResource is a lower level API. You could write your own for the coordinator, but I think that isn't necesary. Instead, leverage JMS + JTA on the coordinator and JTA on the app servers.

In the normal case, you'd have this:

1. Coordinator receives request and starts JTA transaction
2. Coordinator calls app 1 over JMS

   - App 1 receives JMS message
   - App 1 calls DB 1 using JTA
3. Coordinator calls app 2 over JMS

   - App 2 receives JVM message
   - App 2 calls DB 2 using JTA
4. Coordinator commits tx

Note that JTA is used for all the transactions - this will be a global TX that's shared across all the servers. If any of these steps fail, then they will be rolled back.

Spring should be able to make this transparent once you get it all set up. Just make sure your DAO & service calls are transactional. Atomikos will need to be configured so that each server uses the same JTA tx manager.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Is there any sample app for this you aware of? Also how should i call from the coordinator application into the other applications? Do i have to use JMS to propagate the transaction context properly or i can use something else (like Spring HTTP Invoker)?

Comment: Sorry i do understood now that i have to call the other app over JMS. Still, an example would make things even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

REST does support transactions now, via the Atomikos TCC implementation available from www.atomikos.com - it is the actual implementation of the design in the talk you are referring to...

HTH

Comment: Is there any sample code available? I've only found this documentation: http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/TccForRest I don't know which Atomikos edition contains the TCC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a summary of more detailed post:

[How would you tune Distributed ( XA ) transaction for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109373/how-would-you-tune-distributed-xa-transaction-for-performance)

This diagram depicts the comunication flow in between the transaction coordinator and the transatcion participant.
[image]

In your particular case your transaction coordinator will be Atomikos or Bitornix or any other provider. Everythin in the flow belo the end(XID) is completlyinvisible for a developer and is performed only by the transaction coordinator. The first points start,end are within the application scope.

Now based on your question. You can not have distributed transaction in between applications. You can have distributed transaction in between infrastructure that supports them. If you want to have transactions in between application components separated by the network you better use Transaction Compensation and this is a whole different topic.

What you can do with Distributed transaction is from one application, one service, one component whatever enlist multiple databases or resources supporting XA and then execute some transaction.

I see the post below stating Atomikos having some sort of infrastructure supporting XA for REST. In general the classic algorithm for transaction compensation such as Try Cancel Conirm attern is very close to a 2 phase commit protocol. Without looking into the details my guess is that they gave implemented something around this lines.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: @Mogsdad Ok I will do that.