# Shared transaction between multiple applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

we got a requirement of create a transactional operation but handled through multiple applications.

I'm familiar with `@Transactional` annotation to achieve transactions, or for example using it programmatically like:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void doSomething() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.createNativeQuery("...do something...").executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
    em.close();
}
```

So, if I need to allow an app to create a transaction dynamically I could pass `em` as parameter and populate multiple operations from different methods.

However, we got a weird requirement to achieve something like above code but involving multiple applications that share the same database, it would be like a distributed transaction.

Is this feasible with Spring? I'm not sure if I might create some rest services where one of the parameters are the serialized entity managers, although this looks very weird to me. Is it possible to handle like a shared transaction populating operations through multiple apps?

Comment: You can't serialize an entity manager (and you certainly can't send it over the wire). You'll have to use XA transactions / 2 phased commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may involve [XA Transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) over [JTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API#X/Open_XA_architecture). You can use [Spring support for JTA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html) which implies use of particular JTA Transaction Manager implementation under the hood such as [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/Main/WebHome) (paid) or [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm) (Apache-licensed, issues with maintenance now).

Some good overview is also available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/transactions-across-microservices), especially describing the alternatives to XA, including description of eventual consistency

Spring Boot + Atomikos [sample on Github](https://github.com/YihuaWanglv/spring-boot-jta-atomikos-sample) can demonstrate basics of JTA configuration within single application.

Once you get familiar with all of that, you may have similar question [as in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937002/distributed-transactions-across-spring-web-applications). Note, that latter is raised 4 years ago and nothing has changed drastically since that time, so the answers there are still good.

In general, development and implementation of distributed ACID transactions across several applications/services can be a really challenging epic, often comparable by level of effort with re-architecting the whole solution in order to avoid XA usage at all.

Comment: Very interesting, this was what I was looking for. Thanks.